# Manual Extraction of Filter Phase Response with MATLAB using sweep sine

Tags: matlab, filters, phase, frequency-response, sweep

I'm currently at a loss for why my code seems to not be working.  I'm doing a sine sweep on a filter to calculate its freq and phase response.  The frequency response checks out, however the phase response doesn't look right when compared to MATLABs `freqz` function.  Plus since I know the filter is a comb, I can tell its wrong as well.

Here's what I've got so far.

```
%   Filter Coefficients
b = [1];
a = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.96];

%  sweep is my sine wave that goes from 0->fs/2
filtered_sweep = filter(b, a, sweep);

% This section correctly Grabs and plots the Freq Response
fft_sweep = fft(filtered_sweep);
freq_response = abs(fft_sweep);
freq_response = 20*log10(freq_response/1);      % Convert to dB scale
freq_response = freq_response(1:end/2);         % Cut to pi fs/2    
figure;
plot(freq_response);
```

And Now here is where I try and get the Phase two different ways with the same wrong result.  From what I understand to get the phase you just need the angle of the complex values.  In MATLAB I thought angle() should work, but just to be safe I tried to manually compute the angle myself using atan with the imag and real components.

```
% Pre Allocate Vector
% Manual Angle Extraction without using Angle()
phase = zeros(1, length(fft_sweep));
for i=1:length(fft_sweep)
    phase(i) = atan2(imag(fft_sweep(i)), real(fft_sweep(i)));
end

% Using angle()
phase_response = angle(fft_sweep);
phase_response = phase_response(1:end/2);
figure;
plot(unwrap(phase_response));
grid on;
```

Both methods give the same incorrect phase response.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're determining the phase of the system *plus* the phase of the sweep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missing one, very important step. In order to get the impulse response of your filter while using the sweep sine, you must get the output of your system $h[n]$ to excitation with sweep-sine signal $x[n]$:

$y[n]=h[n]\star x[n]$

In your case that's the filtering with `filter` function. Now in order to get the impulse response you must convolve your signal with the *inverse filter* $f[n]$. Generally that's the time-inverted sweep signal (although special kind of pre-conditioning, amplitude scaling, etc. might be done as well):

$h[n]=y[n]\star f[n]$

Now you have your impulse response that you can use for further analysis. Please take a look at this [**answer**](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/15496/8202) tackling very similar problem.

For more theory please see:

> [**A. Farina - Advancements in Impulse Response Measurements by Sine
>   Sweeps**](http://pcfarina.eng.unipr.it/Public/Papers/226-AES122.pdf)
>
> [**A. Farina - Simultaneous Measurement of Impulse Response and Distortion with a
>   Swept-Sine
>   Technique**](http://web.arch.usyd.edu.au/~wmar0109/DESC9090/old/Farina_00.pdf)